# How to set Ethernet as a metered connection in Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I recently switched from Comcast to a locally owned independent ISP for faster speeds (200 Mbps), cheaper prices ($16.99/month) and better customer service, however the only problem I have with that ISP is that they recently added a 50 Gbps/month cap (according to them people were abusing the network by torrenting too much, and using up too much bandwidth). I got a call from them that warned me that I went over my 50 Gbps limit and I'm trying to limit my network usage.

The problem is is that my router is homemade and it runs Windows, and I don't trust other routers such as Netgear and stuff (i.e. that they don't monitor my traffic). It runs Windows Updates and other random crap such as telemetry, Cortana sync, and delivery optimization, and I wanna specify when I want it to connect to the internet to use this (data usage doesn't count during off-peak hours, only during prime hours my usage is counted)...

[image]

I need to set the Ethernet connection as a metered connection (preferably only during on-peak hours), but I can't find where to do this, as the metered connection setting doesn't appear for me for some reason.

[When I contact Microsoft about this problem they simply disconnect the chat without saying anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHQhO.jpg)

Comment: Your router runs Windows, sweet, how'd you do that?

Comment: @InterLinked Using Connectify Hotspot 2017

Comment: You need to be logged in as an admin.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am lol... but someone else figured it out.

Comment: @InterLinked A plus side is that Connectify also blocks ads on all devices, even if they dont support AdBlock, just any ads are completely blocked, and I can also view log reports in Wireshark

Comment: @Kirill2485 Nice, but don't some websites complain about that? I have to disable AdBlock for certain pages and sites. How would you do that with that setup?

Comment: @InterLinked Because the adblocker is built in with Connectify: http://imgur.com/a/wn83M



Or... theres always the HOSTS file, but I dont mess with that.

Comment: @Kirill2485 This also looks like a Wi-Fi product which I don't use. Would it apply to computers connected via Ethernet as well?

Comment: Yes- you just need another ethernet port in your desktop (and preferably a multiple-port switch) - just get a PCI-E ethernet adapter and a multiple-port network switch and broadcast to Ethernet and connect the ethernet adapter from the computer to the network switch, and bam.... you got 10 ethernet ports.

Comment: You trust Microsoft more than Netgear?

Comment: I can view logs through Wireshark, that's why. All the stuff Microsoft spies on me I can log.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on Windows 10 Creator's Update or newer (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1220091/25625) for older versions) click on `Ethernet` on the left hand column, then click on the name of your network connection.

[image]

from there you can flip the switch to set it as a metered connection.

[image]

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I don't see any such option on my system. Is this toggle restricted to certain SKUs?

Comment: @InterLinked not to my knowledge.

Comment: @InterLinked Are you perhaps on the non-insider build? As my other computer which isn't part of Windows Insider doesn't see it.

Comment: @Kirill2485 No, the machine I'm on now is not part of the Insider program (nor are any of the others I use). Plus it runs Pro, not Home, so there might be a delay for updates

Comment: This is only available as of Windows 10 Creator update. On previous build, see Atlas_Gondal answer

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Do you have 2 Ethernet cables plugged into one machine?

Comment: @InterLinked I do have a [Intel DQ77MK motherboad](https://ark.intel.com/products/59044/Intel-Desktop-Board-DQ77MK) which has two eithernet ports on it. However I only have a network cable plugged in to one of them.

Comment: Apparently, nowadays there's a further options in the "details" that supposedly tells windows to "strictly disable all gratuitous traffic from Windows Update and other Windows components". (I don't remember the precise wording.) The default is enable. Before I found out, Windows happily sipped about 100 MB in just a couple dozen seconds out of my 1.2 GB limit on that LTE connection.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use the `Windows key + R` to open the Run command, type `regedit`, and click `OK` to open the Windows registry.
2. Browse the following path:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost
   ```
3. Right-click the **DefaultMediaCost** key and select **Permissions**.[image: Screenshot 1]
4. On the **Security** tab, click the **Advanced** button.[image: Screenshot 2]
5. Next to **TrustedInstaller**, click the Change link.[image: Screenshot 3]
6. Type **Administrators**, and click the Check Names button to make sure you're **typing the correct object**.[image: Screenshot 4]
7. Click **OK**.
8. On the Advanced Security Settings for DefaultMediaCost, **check** the "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects".[image: Screenshot 5]
9. Click **Apply**.
10. Click **OK**.
11. On Permissions for DefaultMediaCost, select the Administrators group, and then make sure to **check** the allow Full Control box.[image: Screenshot 6]
12. Click **Apply**.
13. Click **OK**.
14. On the DefaultMediaCost key, you'll find different entries, including for 3G, 4G, Default, Ethernet, and WiFi with their default data values: 1 or 2. The data value **1 means that the connection type is non-metered**, and the data value of **2 means that the connection type is metered**. **Double-click the Ethernet DWORD (32-bit) Value key, and change the value to 2.**[image: Screenshot 7]
15. Click OK.
16. Close the **registry** and **restart** your computer to complete the process.

**How to Make Sure it's working**

If you want to verify your Ethernet connection is set to metered, you can use apps, such as the desktop version of Outlook, which will detect and alert you that you are using a metered connection, as you probably won't see any "Metered network" statics on the App history tab in Task Manager.[image: Screenshot 8]

**NOTE:**
Once you set a metered connection, the operating system will stop using the internet in many ways. For example:

- Windows updates will no longer download automatically. However, priority updates will continue to download when available.
- Apps will no longer update automatically.
- Live Tiles on the Start menu may stop downloading updates.
- Offline content may not sync with other devices.

In the case you want to **revert to the original settings,** using the same instructions mentioned above, make sure to **change** the Ethernet key data value from **2 to 1**.

Comment: This doesn't work in my Windows10 v1709. Windows still sucking data like anything.